# i want to get student last paid fees from fees table where student id = id

Tags: python, django

**THIS IS MY StudentRegistration MODEL**

```
class StudentRegistration(models.Model):
    #joinId = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone  = models.BigIntegerField()
    age  = models.IntegerField()
    discription  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    joiningDate = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

This is my student and fees models am trying to get the student details and fees deatils. student paid fees every month but i want to get his last payment . now its showing his all payment

**THIS IS MY fees MODEL**

```
class fees(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentRegistration,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paidAmount = models.BigIntegerField()
    balance  = models.BigIntegerField()
    lastFeePaid = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    feeStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py:

```
def student_list(request): 
    students = StudentRegistration.objects.all() 
    fees_paid = fees.objects.latest('lastFeePaid') 
    return render(request, 'student_list.html',{'students':students})
```

Comment: Can you add the code where are getting the wrong result (all payments)?

Comment: i didn't write any code actually i don't  know how to write the code , i want all student details with theire last fee updated date  from these two tables

Comment: def student_list(request):
    students =  StudentRegistration.objects.all()
    fees_paid = fees.objects.latest('lastFeePaid')
    return render(request, 'student_list.html',{'students':students})

Comment: Can you show the result you are getting and the result you are expecting?

Comment: actually i want to display all student details with his last payment . but one student have multiplae entries in fees table beacause every month he should pay the fees, so now am getting all student details with mutiple fees payment deatils

Answer (score 1):

As per the PEP8 convention, Python class names should be in *PascalCase* and here I am changing it for you

```
class Fees(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentRegistration,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paidAmount = models.BigIntegerField()
    balance  = models.BigIntegerField()
    lastFeePaid = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    feeStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Coming to your case, you can use the ***`latest(...)`*** method as

```
last_fee_instance = Fees.objects.filter(student_id=12345).latest("pk")
```

Comment: actually i want to display all student details with his last payment . but one student have multiplae entries in fees table beacause every month he should pay the fees, so now am getting all student details with mutiple fees payment deatils –